# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: How can I mount a temporary volume associated with the workspace in a docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to mount a temporary volume associated with the workspace in a docker container for gradle caching. With Scripted Pipeline, It can be written like the following.

```
docker.image('my-gradle').inside("-v ${pwd(tmp: true)}:/home/jenkins/.gradle") {
    sh './gradlew test'
}
```

But with Declarative Pipeline, the following causes an error.

```
agent {
    dockerfile {
        dir 'path/to/dockerfileDir'
        label 'docker-nodes'
        args "-v ${pwd(tmp: true)}:/home/jenkins/.gradle"
    }
}
```

The console log is like the following.

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -v org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator@34a240ba:/home/jenkins/.gradle ...

java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'e3747815ce1fc12012be2114aa26b6b1ec8a0492'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: create org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator@34a240ba: "org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator@34a240ba" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intented to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:178)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.DockerPipelineFromDockerfileScript.runImage(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/DockerPipelineFromDockerfileScript.groovy:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.configureRegistry(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:68)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.AbstractDockerPipelineScript.run(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/AbstractDockerPipelineScript.groovy:54)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.checkoutAndRun(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:57)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.CheckoutScript.doCheckout(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-extensions/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-extensions.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/CheckoutScript.groovy:40)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript.run(jar:file:/var/jenkins_home/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/agent/impl/LabelScript.groovy:44)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor542.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I mount a temporary volume associated with the workspace in a docker container with Declarative Pipeline?

I posted Jenkins Users group too.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/TVICdTIj6j8

Comment: Looks like the variable is not being interpolated in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this (adapted from [Jenkins Docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/))

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
        image 'maven:3-alpine'
        args '-v $HOME/.gradle:/home/jenkins/.gradle'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn -B'
        }
    }
}
```

}

The volume is not temporal, but I think could work for your use case.

Comment: Can this be done when specifying a dockefile in jenkins pipelines?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Use ```agent { dockerfile true }``` in your pipeline.  For a more in depth example read the jenkins docs: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#dockerfile

Comment: Thanks, I am already using a dockerfile in my pipeline, I wondered whether it was possible to mount volumes using the `dockerfile` declaration?